# How can I access lists that are generated within a function?

Tags: python, list, function, foreach

So I'm a bit stuck with some python homework... this is my first question btw sorry if it's formatted wrong.

There is a function "co-ordinates_generator()" that produces a list of co-ordinates, [[x, y], [x, y], [x, y]] etc.

I must create a function that draws upon these co-ordinates and prints pins onto a map accordingly, using those co-ordinates.
I thought I could achieve this by doing:

```
def place_coords():
     for point in co-ordinates_generator():
           if point[0] == '1': 
                place_pin() etc. etc....
```

This DOES work, however when I do this, the lists produced by "co_ordinates_generator()" are generated TWICE. So in other words, two lists are printed to my screen instead of just a single one that I am supposed to use.

My only assumption is that because in the part:

```
for point in co-ordiantes_generator():
```

I call upon co-ordinates_generator() and doing so triggers the function, causing it print and then also print again when I call place_coords(). Is this correct

If so, or otherwise, how would I go about fixing this? I've tried just deleting the "for **_ in ____" part entirely but then that creates all sorts of troubles like "'pin' is not defined". And also the fact that I've written a whole heap of for-each loops based around using the "for _** in ___" part.

Sorry it's a long one! And thank you in advance.

Comment: please show the function declaration for `co-ordinates_generator()`.

Answer (score 0):

In absence of your function I guess you are not returning any value from the function.

```
def co-ordinates_generator():
    ....   # your existing code
    ....   # your existing code
    ....    # your existing code
    return co-ordiantes_variable # whatever name you have defined for the desired result.

result = co-ordinates_generator()
for point in result:
    ....   # your existing code
    ....   # your existing code
    ....   # your existing code
```